# How to Connect OpenWRT to Hotspot for Package Installation

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openwrt

Resources at hand:

- ASUS RT-AC1200 V1/V2 no WDS on native firmware.
- Samsung galaxy S21 FE (unlimited data plan)
- Laptop with Windows 11.

This [link](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-quick-start/ssh_connect_to_the_internet_and_install_luci) explains how to connect OpenWRT to the internet via lan to install WebUI LUCI

Practically my world has collapsed, because I only have a hostpot from my smartphone (Samsung galaxy S21 FE), so this configuration makes no sense... from the previous link because of the resources I have on hand.

I have managed to install OpenWRT Via Recovery Tool on my router and I am connected to it via SSH using a network cable to the LAN1 port

I want to try the following, connecting OpenWRT to my Hostpot (smartphone) using the router's WiFi antennas, but despite my configuration attempts, whenever I restart the OpenWRT network and ping Google it returns:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ping -c 4 google.com
ping: bad address 'google.com'
```

These are my hotspot data:

> ssid='WIFI-HOSTPOT' 
> key='********'

current configuration:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# uci show wireless
wireless.radio0=wifi-device
wireless.radio0.type='mac80211'
wireless.radio0.path='platform/10300000.wmac'
wireless.radio0.channel='1'
wireless.radio0.band='2g'
wireless.radio0.htmode='HT20'
wireless.radio0.disabled='0'
wireless.default_radio0=wifi-iface
wireless.default_radio0.device='radio0'
wireless.default_radio0.network='lan'
wireless.default_radio0.mode='sta'
wireless.default_radio0.ssid='WIFI-HOSTPOT'
wireless.default_radio0.encryption='psk2'
wireless.default_radio0.key='********'
wireless.radio1=wifi-device
wireless.radio1.type='mac80211'
wireless.radio1.path='pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0'
wireless.radio1.channel='36'
wireless.radio1.band='5g'
wireless.radio1.htmode='VHT80'
wireless.radio1.disabled='1'
wireless.default_radio1=wifi-iface
wireless.default_radio1.device='radio1'
wireless.default_radio1.network='lan'
wireless.default_radio1.mode='sta'
wireless.default_radio1.ssid='WIFI-HOSTPOT'
wireless.default_radio1.encryption='psk2'
wireless.default_radio1.key='********'
```

Note: I have already modified some configuration files to add the DNS: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` in `/etc/config/network` and `/etc/resolv.conf`

What I have found on the internet is how to do the configuration to extend my hostpot, which I don't want it at the momment, it wants to connect openWRT to my hostpot to install LUCI and from LUCI I can manage my network.

Having LUCI installed, I will then configure the router to be a repeater of my hostpot.

**The problem is that currently, having done all of the above, I still have no internet connectivity within OpenWRT.**